# How do I shrink text inside a frame?

Tags: listings, fontsize

How do I shrink the text inside the following frame?

```
\lstset{framexleftmargin=0mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black}}

\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting} 
root@bt:~# nmap -O we****t***.com

Starting Nmap 6.01 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-12-21 15:38 CET
Nmap scan report for we****t***.com (217.6*.***.**)
Host is up (0.0087s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
53/tcp   open   domain
80/tcp   open   http
110/tcp  open   pop3
143/tcp  open   imap
443/tcp  open   https
587/tcp  closed submission
3306/tcp open   mysql
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
Device type: general purpose
Running (JUST GUESSING): Microsoft Windows 7|2008 (90%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7:::enterprise cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008::sp1
Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise (90%), Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP1 (89%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 79.16 seconds
\end{lstlisting}
\end{ttfamily}
```

Unfortunately what I get exceeds the page's margins.

Comment: Please consider going through your other questions and marking one of the answers to them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Comment: I've just  accepted the answer you gave me. I do hope I did what I'm supposed to do

Comment: Please note that you don't _have_ to accept any answers. But _if_ an answer actually helped you then it is also helpful to others browsing this site to be able to see which answers helped most. That is what accepting answers is meant for... So only accept my answer if it actually helped :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably want the `basicstyle` and the `breaklines` options. I recommend reading [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) very comprehensive [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings). All of these options and many more are explained there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{
  framexleftmargin=0mm,
  frame=shadowbox,
  rulesepcolor=\color{black},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines,
  % recommendable when using a monospaced font (see the documentation
  % for details, thanks @egreg for the reminder):
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting} 
root@bt:~# nmap -O we****t***.com

Starting Nmap 6.01 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-12-21 15:38 CET
Nmap scan report for we****t***.com (217.6*.***.**)
Host is up (0.0087s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
53/tcp   open   domain
80/tcp   open   http
110/tcp  open   pop3
143/tcp  open   imap
443/tcp  open   https
587/tcp  closed submission
3306/tcp open   mysql
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
Device type: general purpose
Running (JUST GUESSING): Microsoft Windows 7|2008 (90%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7:::enterprise cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008::sp1
Aggressive OS guesses: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise (90%), Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP1 (89%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 79.16 seconds
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And, possibly, `columns=fullflexible`, as using a fixed width font will guarantee aligment without adding space between characters, which I find terrible.

Comment: @egreg good point!